# CS:GO Won't load on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: games, steam

I recently got Ubuntu 16.04 alongside my Windows 10 installation. I got steam since I mostly use my computer to play games. I downloaded CS:GO and clicked play. First weird thing I noticed. It didn't say "Launching Counter Strike Global Offensive" and it didn't pop up in the dash. On my steam library it said Counter Strike Global Offensive - Running. Everything was still fine on Ubuntu besides the fact that CSGO wont start. Help would be appreciated
Here is what the terminal says when i run CSGO with it:

```
Generating new string page texture 155: 128x256, total string texture memory is 2.67 MB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1468023329)
Game update: AppID 730 "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive", ProcID 5470, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/dylan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/dylan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
pid 5473 != 5472, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/dylan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/dylan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
```

Comment: Instead of launching Steam as you normally do, please open a terminal window (Alt-Ctrl-T) and type `steam`. Then when you try to launch CS:GO, any error messages it's producing should (hopefully) appear in the terminal. Then edit your question to include what it shows.